# php - matrix - where I am making a mistake?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, matrix

Create a program with the following output:

a 00000000 
b 00000000 
c 00000X00 
d 00000000
e 00000000
f 000X0000
g 00000000 
h 00000X00 
  12345678

The user enters two-dimensional array at the beginning of the program. Based on this sequence (coordinates) are drawn X's on the table.

Conditions:
Must be used arrays and loops.

I`m 18 and I started to learn php 2 weeks ago. Im having trouble with this task. Can anyone help me ?  THANKS!

SORRY!

this is what I`ve done:

```
<?php
$input = array(2 => array(5),5 => array(3),7 => array(6));
$range = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$length = 8;

$output = '';
foreach($range as $index => $letter)
{
$output .= "$letter ";

for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
{
$output .= (array_key_exists($index, $input) && in_array($i, $input[$index])) ? 'X' : '0';
}

$output .= "\n";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

i got this output:

a 00000000  
b 00000000 
c 00000X00
d 00000000 
e 00000000 
f 000X0000 
g 00000000
h 000000X0

instead of this:

a 00000000 
b 00000000 
c 00000X00 
d 00000000 
e 00000000 
f 000X0000 
g 00000000 
h 00000X00 
12345678

Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: We are not here to do your project, just assist with bits and bobs that you are stuck on.. Providing you can match the criteria laid out in the StackOverflow FAQ

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: i`ve edited my post... the code i have to get is not the same as code i got..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7 => array(6)` should be `7 => array(5)`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/423262c6a4bcdb8693c179dc620966d779b65a51

Comment: hmm...ok, i`ll try that. just one thing. when i open it in my browser i get the code in one line. how to put it in a new line? <br> ?

Comment: @МаркоЛучић replace `$output .= "\n";` by `$output .= "<br>\n";`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = array(2 => array(5),5 => array(3),7 => array(5));
$range = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$length = 8;

$output = '';
$x='';
foreach($range as $index => $letter)
{
    $output .= "$letter ";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
    {
        $output .= (array_key_exists($index, $input) && in_array($i, $input[$index])) ? 'X' : '0';
    }

    $output .= "\n";
    $x.= 1+$index;
}

$output .= $x;
echo $output;

?>
```

this will output

```
a 00000000
b 00000000
c 00000X00
d 00000000
e 00000000
f 000X0000
g 00000000
h 00000X00
12345678
```